# How to force the binding to update when I close the window?

Tags: objective-c, macos, key-value-observing

I have some `NSTextField` on the `NSWindow`. And I set up the binding of the `NSTextField` to shared user defaults controller. The problem is, when I type in the text field and close the window (Cmd + W), the value is not written to the shared user defaults controller.

But it works when I focus other text field.

So how to force the binding to update? Thanks!

Screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: Post your code — without it there's no telling what it's doing.

Comment: There is no code. Only settings in interface builder. But anyway I will upload the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

OK I find the answer. It is because the binding is not continuous. I have to enable "Continuously Updates Value".

[image]